# Eclipse Kepler RCP CoolBar Actions CSS

Tags: css, eclipse, swt, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-kepler

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18982063/add-toolbar-in-eclipse-rcp-application)'s screenshot, my RCP App has those annoying spaces between actions on the coolbar. My guess is that it's because I'm using deprecated extensions in the `plugin.xml` (i.e. <strike>`viewActions`</strike> `actionSet`s).

For now, I don't want to begin changing all those action implementations to comply with the new rules (mostly because there are A LOT of those actions).

**Question**: Can I somehow apply CSS styling to that `CoolBar` so that extra spaces are grabbed by the actions?

**The road so far**:

1. NO e4 STUFF! [This question does not satisfy mine.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18982063/add-toolbar-in-eclipse-rcp-application)
2. [My other (similar) question. Feel free to complete that guy's answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19594890/eclipse-kepler-rcp-main-toolbar-actions)
3. [RAP CSS - does this apply to RCP as well?](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.rap.help/help/html/reference/theming/CoolBar.html)

Comment: Are you using actionSets to define the actions? Do you have a menuContribution defining the toolbar for the set?

Comment: @greg-449 `actionSet`s to define the actions, and a `menubarPath` path in each action.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the debug plugin which does align the toolbar entries correctly it first defines a toolbar like this:

```xml
<extension 
     point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
  <menuContribution
         locationURI="toolbar:org.eclipse.ui.main.toolbar?after=additions">
      <toolbar
            id="org.eclipse.debug.ui.main.toolbar"
            label="%DebugActionSet.label">
         <separator
               name="breakpointGroup"
               visible="true">
         </separator>
         <separator
               name="threadGroup"
               visible="true">
         </separator>
         <separator
               name="stepGroup">
         </separator>
         <separator
               name="stepIntoGroup">
         </separator>
         <separator
               name="stepOverGroup">
         </separator>
         <separator
               name="stepReturnGroup">
         </separator>
         <separator
               name="emptyStepGroup">
         </separator>
         <separator
               name="renderGroup"
               visible="true">
         </separator>
      </toolbar>
   </menuContribution>
```

and then in the `actionSet` references the defined toolbar:

```
      <action
           toolbarPath="org.eclipse.debug.ui.main.toolbar/breakpointGroup"
           ... other stuff ...
           id="org.eclipse.debug.ui.actions.SkipAllBreakpoints">
     </action>
```

Comment: So how is that toolbar defined? Via `menuContribution`? Also, did you use the Eclipse Spy to get there?

Comment: Sorry part of my answer got lost!

Comment: `actionSets` are deprecated. Anyway, in this case, even with proper implementation, the actions are still buggy (i.e. spaces between them).